# Can't use facebook to authenticate: undefined method 'web_server' for OAuth2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, oauth

Trying to let users sign in / sign up with Twitter and Facebook. Twitter works no problem but the strategy is different for Facebook.

```
undefined method `web_server' for #<OAuth2::Client:0x00000005211d58>
```

Trace shows

```
oa-oauth (0.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:18:in `request_phase'
oa-oauth (0.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:28:in `request_phase'
oa-core (0.0.5) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:25:in `call!'
oa-core (0.0.5) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:19:in `call'
oa-core (0.0.5) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:22:in `call'
warden (1.0.5) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.0.5) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.5) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
```

Anybody else experienced this?

ps. I'm using the following gems:

```
gem 'oa-oauth', :require => 'omniauth/oauth'
gem 'oauth2'
```

I'm not using the full omniauth gem as its addressable dependencies conflict with other gems.

Comment: What version of oauth2 are you using? As far as I can tell, it is updated quite rapidly due to how fast the oauth2 specification changes. I am getting the same problem as you when I use the sorcery gem which attempts to use oauth2 version 0.5.0

Comment: I'm presently using Oauth2 0.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when trying to use facebook_oauth (https://github.com/moomerman/facebook_oauth) on my rails app. After spending an hour or so trying to change its code, i realized it might be easier just to use oauth2 directly. I solved the problem and now there's no need for that intermediate library. Here's how:

In `Gemfile` add

```
gem 'oauth2'
```

Then run

`bundle update`

Then, in your `login_via_facebook` method you either construct the dialog uri manually or use the oauth client something along these lines:

```
oauth_client = OAuth2::Client.new(APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, {
    :authorize_url => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth'
})

redirect_to oauth_client.authorize_url({
    :client_id => APPLICATION_ID,
    :redirect_uri => YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
})
```

If you need to request additional permissions, specify `scope` param in the `authorize_url` call:

```
redirect_to oauth_client.authorize_url({
    :client_id => APPLICATION_ID,
    :redirect_uri => YOUR_REDIRECT_URL,
    :scope => 'offline_access,email'
})
```

Then, in the method that handles YOUR_REDIRECT_URL (i call mine `login_via_facebook_callback`), do something like this:

```
oauth_client = OAuth2::Client.new(APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, {
    :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com',
    :token_url => '/oauth/access_token'
})

begin

  access_token = oauth_client.get_token({
      :client_id => APPLICATION_ID,
      :client_secret => APPLICATION_SECRET,
      :redirect_uri => YOUR_REDIRECT_URL,
      :code => params[:code],
      :parse => :query
  })

  access_token.options[:mode] = :query
  access_token.options[:param_name] = :access_token
  facebook_user_info = access_token.get('/me', {:parse => :json}).parsed

rescue Error => e

  # You will need this error during development to make progress :)
  #logger.error(e)

end
```

Now `facebook_user_info` has the basic user info!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, you should try two things:

1. I also had conflicting gem issues/dependencies issues and resolved them by adding this in my gemfile:

> gem 'omniauth', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git'

1. Try using a rails application template which works remarkably well for starting a Twitter/Facebook app in no time, run this command in your terminal:

> rails new APP_NAME -m https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/raw/master/rails3-mongoid-omniauth-template.rb -T

You can read more about it here:
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-omniauth/wiki/Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

here i came across an example app that demonstrates the use of omniauth along with authlogic
https://github.com/madhums/omniauth-authlogic-demo
hope it helps